# What is the Meaning of spectrum

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Most of us are probably too quick to say yes and too slow to say no. It's worth asking yourself where you fall on that **spectrum**.

What is a spectrum here? I know rainbow spectrum as it has colors comprising of different wavelengths, like red having highest wavelength till violet having lowest (both serve as extremes of spectrum)

But what is the parameter of spectrum in above paragraph and what are the extremes?

Link of article :- https://jamesclear.com/saying-no

Comment: Spectrum implies a *range* of values, a *continuum*, not just a few discrete gradations. Do you understand what the speaker is describing, in terms of human response to yes/no questions, presumably in context of offering assistance?

Comment: I guess he wants to show that there are 2 kinds of extreme people , those who say yes very quickly to anything they are asked to do and others who take very long time to say no ?  I had this thought for a while that saying yes quickly was equivalent to taking lot of time to say no

Comment: No, specifically **not two kinds**. There are more than two colors in a spectrum.

Comment: I mean these 2 would be the extremes (like red and violet serve as extremes in a rainbow, and other colors fall in between these 2) and other kinds of people will have traits in between these 2 extremes

Comment: Have you looked this up in a dictionary?

Comment: a range of different positions, opinions, etc. between two extreme points (C1 meaning in this link - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spectrum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scientifically, *spectrum* is a range of waves (or of their frequencies, lengths).

[In the 1930s](https://www.etymonline.com/word/spectrum), the word evolved to have a figurative meaning, and gained a broader scope: [a range of similar things; a range of objects, ideas, or opinions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spectrum) (it's your link, just scroll down a bit).

It's confusing because the first sentence poorly describes "the spectrum" mentioned in the next sentence. Clearly, "people too quick to say yes" and "people too slow to say no" can't be the extremes because there are 2 parameters involved: the response itself (yes or no) and the eagerness of it.

What the author is presumably referring to is the "yes-to-no spectrum". He argues that most people tilt towards the yes side, whereas "saying no keeps you toward the easier end of this spectrum."

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :) , so basically eagerness to say yes or no is not a part of the spectrum , it is just the yes and no which are forming the particular spectrum?

Comment: yes, it can't be. If there was such a range, what would you put in the middle? What would be at the extremes? (I can be eager to say yes, I can be unwilling to say yes. I want to say no, I can be reluctant to say no.) You would need a 2-dimensional space for that.